# Fragment Instantiation crash

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity

Some of my users are experiencing crashes, and this is the error that shows in the crash report on the Google Play Developer Console:

`Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.havens1515.autorespond/com.havens1515.autorespond.SettingsMenuNew}: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.havens1515.autorespond.NotificationOptions: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public`

The users say that this occurs when opening any settings menu inside of `SettingsMenuNew` wich is mentioned in the error above, but I don't experience the crash on my phone. `SettingsMenuNew` is a `PreferenceActivity` and all of the submenus are `PreferenceFragment`

Each `PreferenceFragment`  has an empty constructor, and I don't know what else the issue could be. I also saw in someone else's question that it needs the `newInstance` method, but I don't think I really need that if I'm not putting any other arguments into the fragment.

here is some the code showing those methods:

```
public class NotificationOptions extends PreferenceFragment
{
    public NotificationOptions()
    {

    }

    public static NotificationOptions newInstance(int title, String message)
    {
        NotificationOptions f = new NotificationOptions();
        return f;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: If NotificationOptions is an inner class it should be static.

Comment: It's not an inner class, it's in its own file

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add it to proguard exception or using wrong proguard config.

Comment: That might be the issue. I'll look into it a bit. I don't know a whole lot about how proguard works, so I might have to do some research.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but it is only on foreign mobile phones. I have noticed that some people have the developer options "do not keep activities" checked, which causes the app to crash when it goes back to the main activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This probably happens due to proguard removing your Fragments.

To reproduce, build the obfuscated APK, enable "Don't Keep Activities" in developer options, open the Activity wich contains the Fragment that crashes. Minimize on home button and restore app from recents.

To merge proguard configurations with default one and yours in ADT you should specify in project.properties

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

If you're using Gradle build system

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        runProguard false
    }

    release {
        runProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}
```

And proguard-project.txt should contain at least these rules

```
-keep public class * extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment
```

And if you're using support Fragments

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

Don't forget that there are already some rules contained in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt so add only missing based on your needs.

Comment: I think I need to add `-keep public class * extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment` as well, since these classes are PreferenceFragment, not Fragment or FragmentActivity.

Comment: That did work. Thanks a lot! I've been trying to figure this out for about a week

Comment: @Randy you are correct. I forgot to mention PreferenceFragment.