# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException for onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin

I see crashes in the Google Play crash log that is really stumping me.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3086)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3229)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1926)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6981)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1445)
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:462)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java:50)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate (FragmentState.java:80)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState (FragmentManager.java:3109)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState (FragmentController.java:158)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:344)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:85)
  at com.autotask.jbarra.kotlinmvvm.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.kt:102)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7326)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7317)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1271)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3066)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0 (Class.java:2328)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor (Class.java:1725)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:443)
```

the thing is, line 102 of Main activity is nothing special

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) //This is line 102
```

What could cause this?  Why is oncreate throwing no such method?  It's happening on a few user's devices and I haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: Share your xml layout

Comment: Did you solve this? 0-arg constructor did not help me at all. For me it looks like it's Proguard. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The activity is being restored from an instance state bundle. Part of the restore operation is recreating its fragments.

Your activity has a fragment and the fragment class does not have a 0-arg constructor required by the framework.

Comment: I will look into that.  Do you have any tips on how to reproduce the crash?

Comment: "Don't keep activities" developer setting forces activities to save state when going to another activity, triggering a restore when coming back.

Comment: Do you know @laalto if by any chance the ```NoSuchMethodException``` has associated the name of the ```Fragment``` that is failing to meet this situation? I believe I've isolated the case but I'm not sure cause I wasn't able to reproduce this error on my own device / emulator.

Comment: @xarlymg89 Yes; Google Play developer console however eats away exception details. You can use some other crash reporting tool such as Crashlytics to get exception message details included.

Comment: I'm actually using Crashlytics too, however that very exception didn't show up there. Will have to wait to see if it's been solved or not then :) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @laalto How to fix this issue ?

Comment: @ch3tanz remove explicit constructor(s) or add a 0-arg one.

Comment: @laalto I'm using navigation graph for fragments with androidx library

Comment: @xarlymg89 That's very strange - we're seeing this error as well, and our other crash reporting systems did not report it. The only place the error is showing up is the Play Console.

Comment: no one has full explanation and how to solve it ? i have the 0 arg constructor and still get this error...

Answer (score 9):

I'm having the same issue. The other answers did not help.

For me, it looks like it is Proguard. That explains why it only happens in production/release builds and why I have been unable to reproduce it when debugging.

If you're having OP's issue, try the following:

1. Build the obfuscated .apk. I used the signed one, that I publish to the app stores...
2. Enable "Don't Keep Activities" in your device's developer options.
3. Install the .apk in your device and open the Activity that crashes and contains the Fragment.
4. Leave your app (Minimize / Home button / ...) and re-open it from the recent apps menu.

Does it crash? Then try it with the un-obfuscated debug build. If it doesn't then it's probably Proguard.

To fix it I did the following:

1. Create a proguard-rules.pro file in your app module's root folder.
2. Add -keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment{} to that file.
3. Then, in the app's build.gradle,

add:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

See Yaroslav Mytkalyk's answer here: [Fragment Instantiation crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562148/fragment-instantiation-crash), which helped me solve this, although it's a bit old and outdated by now (e.g. "runProguard true" is obsolete).

At least now it doesn't crash when I do the steps above.

*PS: I did this in conjunction with adding the 0-arg constructors to my fragments, as mentioned in other answers, since that was my first fixing attempt. I believe that Proguard alone was the issue and that it isn't necessary to add said constructors, but I cannot test that hypothesis now.*

Comment: With this rule, all of your fragments will not minified and it's not a good practice

Comment: True. But adding the 0-arg constructor didn't help. I'm more than open to an alternative (and proper) way of solving this, if anyone knows one.

Comment: This wasn't the problem for me, but these steps allowed me to finally reproduce the problem on my devices, which was very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

My Activity had a `FragmentPagerAdapter` that was using the deperecated constructor.
I changed

```
class MyPagerAdapter(
        fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
        private val myActivity: MyActivity
    ) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) // DEPRECATED
```

to

```
class MyPagerAdapter(
        fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
        private val myActivity: MyActivity
    ) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT)
```

Seem to have fixed the problem

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter was the problem for mine, after changing to FragmentPagerAdapter worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After some search i finally fix the issue. You have to check 3 things.

1. You should have a 0-arg constructor in the fragment, best practice is to do something like bellow
2. If you are using callback in the caller, you have to check if getContext is `null` or not (otherwise you will get a NullPointerException)
3. Don't forget to test the case when the screen orientation change, this will allow you to reproduce some potential issue due to restoring fragment state

Sample code example :

```
    public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{
     private String id;

     public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String id) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment ();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        if(id!= null){
            args.putString("id", id);
        }
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            id= savedInstanceState.getString("id");
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As already said the problem is a missing 0-arg constructor in the Fragment.
In my case the constructor was removed from a `DialogFragment` by the code shrinking of the release variant.

To reproduce the crash, build the app with `minifyEnabled true`, popup the DialogFragment and rotate the device screen.

A simple solution to keep the 0-arg constructor is to add a `@Keep` annotation:

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Keep
    public MyDialogFragment() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin, here's an example of the problematic constructor syntax and how to rewrite it. The first line is the constructor, and it has an argument. This was causing the `getConstructor0` crash when the app was shut down and Android tried restoring it:

```
open class MyFragment(parent: MyClass) : Fragment() {
    var parent = parent
}
```

The following rewrite avoids the crash. The first line is the 0-argument constructor and the second line is the custom constructor:

```
open class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    constructor(parent: MyClass): this() {
        this.parent = parent
    }

    lateinit var parent: MyClass
}
```

When you instantiate the class like `MyFragment(parent)`, it works the same as before. However, when Android restores the app, it will call `MyFragment()`, so you will need to account for the class running with the uninitialized variable. You can check for `this::parent.isInitialized` if needed.

Instead of describing the problem as, “You need a 0-argument constructor,” it’s easier for me to understand as, “You can’t pass an argument when creating a fragment (unless you’re prepared for that argument to not be set).”

This took a while to understand because most of my fragment classes don’t have arguments and I couldn’t see what I was doing wrong. But I had one child fragment of a child fragment that I had set up to take an argument. That class name wasn’t showing in the Google Play Console crash logs, but when I followed the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63060778/462162) to reproduce the problem, it did show in the Android Studio console, and then this finally became clear.

The Google Play crash logs only showed this:

```
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
```

But the Android Studio console showed this, where the crash happens in the FormList class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.arlomedia.bandhelper.superclasses.FormList.<init> []
```

Changing your design to avoid the constructor argument altogether might be a better solution for your situation. In my case, the variable is an object, so I can't save it and restore it from a bundle. I didn't want to make it optional because it will always be set when the app runs normally. And my app will reload its interface after relaunching anyway, so I just need to get through Android's restore attempt without crashing.

Answer (score -2):

System not able to restore your fragment due to missing zero-argument constructor for your fragment.

Adding a zero-argument constructor to all your fragment will solve error.

```
public YourFragment() {}
```