# Fragment$InstantiationException | NoSuchMethodException on Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console

Based on some answers have added a default constructor to Fragments, but still, we are getting below crashes on the play console.

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3488)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3635)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner (ActivityThread.java:5582)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5490)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute (ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2175)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7860)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:94)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:9)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init> (FragmentStateManager.java:10)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState (FragmentManager.java:96)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java:8)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:17)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:10)
  at com.companyname.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.java)
  at com.companyname.activities.Activity1.onCreate (Activity1.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7955)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7944)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1307)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3463)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3635)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner (ActivityThread.java:5582)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5490)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute (ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2175)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7860)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: 
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0 (Class.java:2332)
  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor (Class.java:1728)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:15)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate (FragmentContainer.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate (FragmentManager.java:9)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init> (FragmentStateManager.java:10)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState (FragmentManager.java:96)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState (FragmentController.java:8)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:17)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:10)
  at com.companyname.activities.BaseActivity.onCreate (BaseActivity.java)
  at com.companyname.activities.Activity1.onCreate (Activity1.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7955)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7944)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1307)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3463)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3635)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner (ActivityThread.java:5582)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5490)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute (ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2175)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7860)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56668934/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-for-oncreate> has steps to reproduce. read through the comments

Comment: Have you found something in common on crash reports? Device model, android version, manufacturer etc. This may help you reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

did you make Constructor without any params?

for example,

```
public YourFragment() {
  // Do not anything!!!
}
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce, but it is happening only on the play console...Went through the above link all the answers mentioned over there taken care of but still in play console issues coming up

Comment: Even I'm facing the exact same problem what @girish said here, I too have default constructor with no arguments. Also Im using Kotlin not java. Any clue why this can happen other then standard normal answers

Comment: same error. it's exist several time but I can't reproduce.

Comment: @Khay Same prob what you've. I started a bounty for this question.